# Angularjs Form data is not binding at server side during file uploade

Tags: angularjs

When im tring to uploade my file into server im getting an Error as  `TypeError: $http(...).success is not a function(…)`

Angular File change code

```
 $scope.ChechFileValid = function (file) {
        debugger;
        var isValid = false;
        if ($scope.SelectedFileForUpload != null) {
            if ((file.type == 'image/png' || file.type == 'image/jpeg' || file.type == 'image/gif') && file.size <= (512 * 1024)) {
                $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "";
                isValid = true;
            }
            else {
                $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "Selected file is Invalid. (only file type png, jpeg and gif and 512 kb size allowed)";
            }
        }
        else {
            $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "Image required!";
        }
        $scope.IsFileValid = isValid;
    };
```

This is my file submit button Code

```
$scope.SaveFile = function () {
        $scope.IsFormSubmitted = true;
        $scope.Message = "";
        $scope.ChechFileValid($scope.SelectedFileForUpload);
        if ($scope.IsFormValid && $scope.IsFileValid) {
            FileUploadService.UploadFile($scope.SelectedFileForUpload, $scope.FileDescription).then(function (d) {
                alert(d.Message);
                ClearForm();
            }, function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        }
        else {
            $scope.Message = "All the fields are required.";
        }
    };
```

This is my factory code

```
 fac.UploadFile = function (file, description) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);        
        formData.append("description", description);

        var defer = $q.defer();
      return  $http({
          url: 'http://localhost:59838/Api/Home/Sales',
          data: JSON.stringify(formData),

          headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          method: 'POST',

        })
        .success(function (d) {
            defer.resolve(d);
        })
```

Here im getting Error as angular.js:15018 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:59838/Api/Home/Sales'.","Message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the *$http(...).success is not a function(…)*
because the "**.success**" method has since been deprecated, use "**.then**" instead. More info on the following link [Check Deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

As for the second error, it could be the result of improper URI, maybe your route is expecting a query parameter, ie : http://localhost:59838/Api/Home/Sales?**XXXX**, check the full error for more infos

> ie : (No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI ..."
>   (parameter **XXXX** is mandatory))